# How feature importance and forest structures are related in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, data-science, ensemble-learning

Here is a simple example of my problem, using the Iris dataset.
I am puzzled when trying to understand how feature importance are computed and how this is visible when visualizing the forest of estimators using `export_graphviz`.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = load_iris()
X = pd.DataFrame(data=data.data,columns=['sepallength', 'sepalwidth', 'petallength','petalwidth'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data=data.target)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2,max_depth=1)
rf.fit(X_train,y_train.iloc[:,0])
```

The classifier performs poorly (the score is 0.68) since the forest contains 2 trees with depth of 1. Anyway this doesn't matter here.

The feature importance are retrieved as follow:

```
importances = rf.feature_importances_
std = np.std([rf.feature_importances_ for tree in rf.estimators_],axis=0)
indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

print("Feature ranking:")
for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %s (%f)" % (f + 1, X.columns.tolist()[f], importances[indices[f]]))
```

and the output is :

```
Feature ranking:
1. feature sepallength (1.000000)
2. feature sepalwidth (0.000000)
3. feature petallength (0.000000)
4. feature petalwidth (0.000000)
```

Now when showing the structure of trees that are built using the following code:

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(rf.estimators_[0],
                feature_names=X.columns,
                filled=True,
                rounded=True)
!dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree0.png
from IPython.display import Image
Image('tree0.png')
```

I obtain these 2 figures

- export of tree #0:

[image]

- export of tree #1:

[image]

I cannot understand how `sepallength` can have **importance=1 but not be used** for node splitting in both trees (only `petallength` is used) as shown in the figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in

```
for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %s (%f)" % (f + 1, X.columns.tolist()[f], importances[indices[f]]))
```

If you permute with `indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]`, then you need to permute *everything* - not keep the labels according to one ordering, and the importances according to a different ordering.

If you replace the above by

```
for f in range(X.shape[1]):
    print("%d. feature %s (%f)" % (f + 1, X.columns.tolist()[f], importances[f]))
```

then the forest and its trees are all in agreement that the feature at index 2 is the only one with any importance.